# Long lived Facebook token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling to get the 60 day valid token for the last few hours. I have created a test app in Facebook which is not public. For obvious reason because it does nothing.

I made a request:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={user-60min-valid-token}

And I got this response:

> {u'error': {u'message': u'The access token does not belong to application 1234287494356751', u'code': 1, u'type': u'OAuthException'}}

I need the persistent token for querying from the graph api some fan page of interest, is there a way to get it for this purpose or some other way? I checked the user access token in the Debug section and is still valid.

Comment: And what does the debug tool say, which application does the token belong too …?

Comment: To 145634995501895 : Graph API Explorer. Could not manage to link the token to the aforementioned app. The button Get app token is grey (disabled).

Comment: So you are using the wrong short-lived user access token … get one for the actual app that your are making the call to extend the token for/with.

Comment: How can i get it, I tried with ../endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret, but unsuccessful?

Comment: If you only need it once: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/ Otherwise, implement a proper login flow for your app.

Comment: OK, I set it. Now i get the error No user access token specified. I tried to set the access_token in the params, how to do it right :) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57192/discussion-between-xplorer00-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1):

I I made a Python script to solve my problem where i used the library facepy(https://github.com/jgorset/facepy):

```
from facepy import get_extended_access_token
from facepy import GraphAPI

application_id=''
application_secret=''
app_access_token='app_id|....' #https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
user_token='' #generated from the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
long_lived_access_token, expires_at = get_extended_access_token(user_token,
    application_id, application_secret)

print long_lived_access_token+' '+str(expires_at)
```

Output:

> some_long_token 2014-09-10 01:10:04.384503

If someone knows how to do the same thing with curl/requests, I'll be glad to know it.